# How to return 1 if both number share sign without if statements?

Tags: c

Let's say I have two variables.

```
int a = -10;
int b = 10;
```

How can I return 0 if they have different sign or 1 if they have same signs ?
Again without if statements

Comment: Hint: you can just return the value of a comparison, you don't have to use it inside `if`.  And the value of a comparison can itself be compared to things.

Comment: You can xor the most significant bits of both numbers, if You want to avoid machine code branching.

Comment: @RomanHocke not sure how portable that is. And the goal is to return 0 or 1 and not the result of an xor operation.

Comment: @RomanHocke That does not itself give you a 1 or 0.  You'd have to perform a logical-not operation on the results.  And to double-down on Richard's concerns, I do not believe there is a guarantee in the C standard that the MSb will contain a sign-signifying bit (though I'd be hard-pressed to find an implementation that doesn't).  Plus that implementation requires knowing how many bits are in a given type you are comparing against and bit-masking, so you'd probably need different versions for different types or force some integral promotion magic.

Comment: You are both correct, I just mentioned it as an interesting option.

Comment: If we don't care about `0` you could try this: `return (a>=0) == (b>=0);`

Comment: @Gerhardh or what about `return ((a >= 0) & (b >= 0));`?

Comment: @RichardChambers This only works for +/+, +/-, -/+ but fails for -/-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this?

```
return ((a >= 0 && b >= 0) || (a < 0 && b < 0));
```

Comment: Well 0 is netiher positive nor negative but I treat it as positive now since it has to be something. I could ofcourse add `a==0 && b==0` to it.

Comment: @pmg Well the question does specify the "sign", rather than "positive" and "negative", and "-0" does have a negative sign.  Granted, if we accept a negative zero as a possibility, I'm not quite sure how to portably consider it.

Comment: Let's just call "the sign of `0` (`-0` included)" UB!

Comment: @pmg Ah, good call.  Undefined Behavior is incredibly portable.

Answer (score 5):

As the question is probably only theoretically relevant (homework?), I will ignore the correct handling of value 0.
You would need to define if it is positive, negative or both.

1.

```
return (a>=0) == (b>=0);
```

2.

```
return ((double)a*b) > 0;
return ((double)a/b) > 0;
```

(Convert to double to avoid overflow.) 
Warning: Division by zero might occur.

Comment: I like your "1." I'm not sure when your "2." would be needed, and the second line (if reached) could result in division by 0.

Comment: @Gerhardh that is for a homework indeed. 
I like your "1" too.

Comment: The second option you have here has a potential divide-by-zero.  Could be troublesome depending on how the implementation handles such a condition for floating-point types.  Ignoring getting it correct for both `a` and `b` being zero, having it not result in potentially undefined behavior would probably be preferable.

Comment: You are right. Division by zero may be a risk. But as mentioned correct handling of 0 is ignored. For a homework assignment the OP can fill in missing checks. Any real world assignment would not require to avoid `if` anyway.

Comment: @IanAbbott Option 2 would never be needed. The whole constraint to avoid `if` would probably never be needed as well.

Comment: the second solution would be slow

Answer (score 2):

```
int msb = 1u << (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT  - 1);
return !((msb & a) ^ (msb & b));
```

Comment: You can use `INT_MIN` for msb, it is `1000...000` in binary.

Comment: `1<<31` unfortunately invokes undefined behavior, so this isn't a good solution. If you want to calculate the mask, use unsigned type: `1u << (sizeof...`

Answer (score 2):

The obscure but probably quite effective version would be this:

```
#include <limits.h>

return !((a & INT_MIN) ^ (b & INT_MIN));
```

Explanation:

No matter signed representation on the given system, the MSB of the variable will always hold a sign bit. By checking if the sign bit is set on each variable, we can see if it is signed or not.

This is done by bitwise masking, for example `a & 0x80000000` on a 32 bit system. This returns `0x80000000` if the number is signed, otherwise `0`.

The portable version of the 0x80... mask is `INT_MIN` from limits.h.
(Or if you will, you can use `1u << (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int))`).

You want to return 1 if the variables have the same sign, otherwise 0. That is logical XNOR. C does not have that operator but we can create it through `!(a ^ b)`, read as "NOT (a XOR b)".

And so we end up with the above expression. For those who doesn't know the difference in operator precedence between bitwise AND and bitwise XOR (*gasp*, shame on you!), I added the inner parenthesis, although you can also drop them if you wish to pose with your C operator precedence knowledge:

```
return !( a & INT_MIN ^ b & INT_MIN );
```

Comment: Are you certain `INT_MIN` is portably equivalent of `0x8000...`?  I believe a sign-and-magnitude representation would be legal in C, and in that case, I would expect `INT_MIN` would be `0xFFFF...`.  Of course, if you asked me to find such a system, I'd wave a white flag.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Ah yeah you are right, it wouldn't be portable to them pesky signed magnitude CPU:s, but to the similarly common one's complement ones. Uh, I don't think anyone needs to care about that though, the main portability issue is the size of int. But the snippet I posted as alternative to INT_MIN should cover all your signed magnitude needs, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algebraic solution. Just if you are sure that neither a or b is 0.

`return abs(a/abs(a) + b/abs(b))/2;`

Comment: This results in division by 0 if a is 0 or b is 0.

Comment: and it's also very slow